# How can I only allow certain domains in email field?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possibly to restrict sign up to only one domain like user@gmail.com? Here is my HTML page so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/umfiles/style.css"         media="screen"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;"/>
  <title>User Signup</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/umfiles/general.js"></script>

<body>

<form name="signup" action="" method="post"
    onsubmit="return checkSignupForm()">
  <input type="hidden" name="signup" value="start" />

<div id="cntr_container">  
<table id="cntr_conttable">
    <tr>
      <td id="cntr_conttd">
    <div id="cntr_continner">
      <div class="shadow">
        <div class="shadow-inner">
          <div class="shadow-cnt">
            <div id="cntr_logo">
              <img src="/umfiles/logo.gif" alt="Mikrotik" />

              <p id="logo_title">TITLE</p>
            </div>

            <table class="cntr_tbl">
              <tr>
                <td align="right">
                  email
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                  <input type="text" id="sf_email" name="email" 
                         class="signup" value="$(email)" maxlength="100"
                         autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td align="right">
                  phone
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                  <input type="text" id="sf_phone" name="phone" 
                         class="signup" value="" maxlength="100"
                         autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td align="right">
                  login
                </td>

                <td align="left">
                  <input type="text" 
                         name="login" id="sf_user" maxlength="100"
                         value="$(login)" class="signup"
                         autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td align="right">
                  password
                </td>

                <td align="left">
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="sf_pwd"
                         class="signup" maxlength="50">
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td align="right">
                  confirm password
                </td>

                <td align="left">
                  <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="sf_cnf_pwd"
                         class="signup" maxlength="50">
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr class="top">
                <td align="right">
                  <br />
                  <b>Prepaid time</b>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr class="top">
                <td align="right">
                  time (price)
                </td>

                <td align="left">
                  $(profiles)
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr class="top" id="method_row">
                <td align="right">
                  pay with
                </td>

                <td align="left">
                  $(methods)
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>                
                <td colspan="2" align="right">
                  <input type="submit" name="btn_signup" id="btn_signup" value="Sign up">
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>                
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                  <p class="signuperror">$(error)</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </td>
</tr>   
</table>
</div>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
  if (document.signup && document.signup.user) document.signup.user.focus();

  function checkSignupForm() {
    if (!checkEmail("sf_email")) return false;
    if (!checkMinLen("sf_user", "Login", 3)) return false;
    if (!checkMinLen("sf_pwd", "Password", 5)) return false;
    if (!checkAreEqual("sf_pwd", "sf_cnf_pwd", "Passwords differ")) return      false;
    return true;
  } 

  -->
</script>

</body>
```

I believe the part that needs looked at is the bottom javascript section. I apologize for the question, but this got thrown onto me and I know nothing about html and/or javascript. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You should verify domain on server side, because user can easily disable JavaScript and use another domain as well.

Comment: What do you mean server side? I don't think I have that option on what I'm doing this on. I am not too worried about users disabling javascript, this will be for a fairly small pool of not too technical users.

Comment: How are you sending your data further, then?

Comment: This is only to sign up for local guest internet access

Comment: And what are you going to do with this data? Process? Store somewhere? What will be your form's `action=""`? If it just goes to vacuum (as it does now), why bother checking?

Comment: It is a usermanager form for a Mikrotik Routerboard. It does use a database but once again, I have no idea on how I would restrict that.